# how get the "parent name" and read the object in the ng-repeat AngujarJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

if i have a response object like this:

[image]

[Object Json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqJ9Z.png) from my js file and i need use the ng-repeat for this element but i need to get the name "street 1" too, how can use the ng-repeat for get all values with the "parent name" and his properties. Thanks

Comment: Use the `(key, value)` form of `ng-repeat`. See [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - arguments](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#ngRepeat-arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```html
<div ng-repeat = "(key ,value) in YourObject">
   <div class = "title">{{key}}</div> <!-- name of object e.g street1-->
   <div class = "body">contract : {{value[0].contract}} status: {{value[0].status}}</div>
   <div class = "body">contract : {{value[1].contract}} status: {{value[1].status}}</div>
</div>
```

or

```html
<div ng-repeat = "(key ,value) in YourObject">
   <h1 class = "title">{{key}}</h1> <!-- name of object e.g street1-->
   <div class = "body" ng-repeat = "item in value">
        {{item.contract}} / {{item.status}} 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing an '=' in the second ng-repeat, but all works perfectly